# Generating realizations from $n$-dimensional geometric Brownian motion where the variables are constrained to sum to 1

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-motion

Is there a way to simulate an $N$-dimensional geometric Brownian motion i.e. variable $$x_i, i \in  [1, N] $$ is diffusing in log-space such that $$\log (x_i)$$ follows a Brownian motion with a given mean and variance and sum of all $x_i$ is constrained to be $1.$  I don't know much about this topic so any references would be really useful.

Additionally can mean and variance of each variable be selected independently of each other.

Comment: In "Diffusions on the Simplex from Brownian Motions on Hypersurfaces" they obtain explicit SDE systems for BMs in simplices. So I suppose one can then start from simulating those.

Comment: I have solved the problem approximately i think the reference above is kind of too complicated there is a simpler solution possible i will post it after i have perfected it or published it somewhere